# Updating write capacity to global Dynamo table with replicas and indices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, capacity-planning

In [Best practices and requirements for managing global tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/globaltables_reqs_bestpractices.html) it says that when adjusting capacity settings for tables with replicas, we should use `UpdateGlobalTableSettings` over `UpdateTable` or some others because the latter requires individually updating the capacity for each replica and all its associated GSIs. But it seems from [the doc on UpdateGlobalTableSettings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateGlobalTableSettings.html) that that operation only applies to the legacy version of global tables. What would be the correct approach to update capacity for all replicas and indices with the current version of global tables?

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of global tales you should use `UpdateTable` to manage and/or update your tables.

The link you shared is from the legacy section of the docs.

Comment: So does that mean we have to individually set the capacity for every replica and index in the request?

Comment: The writes will propagate to all replicas, the reads are independent to each replica.